# How does one Configure Arch Linux Raspberry Pi 4B for Bluetooth Headset?

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, arch-linux, raspberry-pi

#### Obsolete Instructions for Earlier Raspberry Pi Models (e.g. RPi3)

The information below is what I had originally posted as attempted solutions but failed to playback audio satisfactorily. In other words, they do not work on RPi4.

> I followed the pulseaudio install instructions on the linked page
>   below but it could not find the bluetooth controller and the `power on`
>   command in `bluetoothctl` resulted in `No default controller available`
>   error.
>
> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Configuration_via_CLI
>
> When I follow the instructions I found on the linked page below, it
>   fails to install because of `linux-raspberrypi4` conflict.
>
> https://github.com/RoEdAl/alarm-bluetooth-raspberrypi

Comment: You might want to split this into a question and answer pair

Comment: When I post a question and it's viewed 50+ times with no response, I continue to experiment until I find a solution. At that point, I have the answer to the question. So, I then have two options: Answer my own question or post the answer. Since SuperUser discourages answering my own question, I went with the solution to post. Somewhere there should be a reason to post solutions without a question when no one answers it.

Comment: I don't get why you think we discourage you answering your own question. There's a checkbox, and as a mod - I speak for the site where I say "You need to split this up"

Comment: The question I posted contained a lot of misinformation where I searched and found outdated answers. So I cleaned up my question and found that only a small portion was relevant to the solution. At that point, my answer would be more confusing than just posting the solution. I prefer to communicate clearly without misinformation and nebulous Q&A formats and rules:  "If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says 'Answer your own question' at the bottom of the Ask Question page." I don't have 15 "reputations."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution I found to auto-connect bluetooth headsets to Raspberry Pi 4B running Arch Linux ARM 4.19.71. These instructions use some source code from Raspbian Buster to setup the RPi4B hardware to work with pulseaudio and bluetoothctl. There were no responses to my question here on SuperUser nor on Raspberry Pi Foundation forums. These files need to be installed (copied) to route the audio through a RPi4B UART serial channel to the headset.

One reason I am posting this is to get any recommendations on how I implemented this software solution. I figured if Buster worked and it is based on the new RPi4B hardware, then the same should work on Arch Linux, and some uart/serial files already exist on Arch.

One last point is that if there are issues with these instructions on a particular RPi4B unit, there have been [reports of RPi4B hardware failure with bluetooth and Wi-Fi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=247721). I used these instructions below multiple times and hopefully corrected any mistakes. If you have tried these instructions and something fails to work, please leave a comment and I’ll attempt to respond.

Download `btuart` and `hciuart.service` files:
https://gist.github.com/frankgould/db38ca5e40b3d2368f8d7765e346f8c5

All of these installation/configuration commands are entered in a terminal window.

NOTE: The instructions below can be copied from one raw file using the link at the bottom of this post in the References section. That way, you can copy more lines of commands without the descriptions included in this page. In these descriptions, I have attempted to describe what the next commands are accomplishing.

Any place with angle brackets, or “<” and “>”, are indications where your information should be typed or pasted without the brackets. For instance, `/home/<your-folder>` should be input as `/home/archpi` when using a default user name of `archpi`.

Install `pulseaudio` and `bluetooth`:

```
sudo pacman -S pulseaudio-alsa pulseaudio-bluetooth bluez-utils libmm-glib modemmanager
sudo systemctl start ModemManager
sudo systemctl enable ModemManager
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

Test case command below - Should be clean startup, if not, see if there are recommendations in the startup results of the command below or your boot `journalctl -b`.

```
systemctl status ModemManager
```

Copy `btuart` script to `/usr/bin folder` and `chmod 777` to execute:

```
sudo cp <folder-containing-btuart-file>/btuart /usr/bin/.
sudo chmod 777 /usr/bin/btuart
```

Copy `hciuart.service` to `/etc/systemd/system` folder to auto-start uart services at boot:

```
sudo cp <folder-containing-hciuart.service-file>/hciuart.service /etc/systemd/system/.
```

Add permanent link for `serial1`to `ttyAMA0` as `udev` rule for serial audio channel:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99_ttyAMA0.rules 
KERNEL=="ttyAMA0", SYMLINK+="serial1"
```

Save the file above and reboot to setup the permanent link.

```
reboot
```

Login as your user, then

```
cd /home/<your-folder>
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/hciattach-rpi3.git
cd hciattach-rpi3/
makepkg -Asri
```

**Note**: You may need to install any new dependencies since this post was published. For instance, `patch` may not be installed. To fix that, run `sudo pacman -S patch` and try the `makepkg` command above again.

Test with command below and results should show help text indicating operational install.

```
hciattach-rpi3
```

Create a copy of `hciattach` without `-rpi3` to work with `btuart` script and startup `bluetooth` and `hciuart` services:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/hciattach-rpi3 /usr/bin/hciattach
sudo systemctl start hciuart
sudo systemctl enable hciuart
```

#### Scan for Bluetooth Headset and Connect

This following section is well documented on many sites and are consistent. In these instructions below, after starting the `bluetoothctl` app, each command needs to be entered, followed by the return/enter key.

After entering the `scan on` instruction, any bluetooth devices in your nearby area should appear as a MAC address (i.e. `##:##:##:##:##:##` or example `01:23:45:67:89:AB`) along with your headset name. You will need to type or copy/paste the MAC address following each `pair`, `connect`, and `trust` command.

If you have problems with the `power on` command, it’s most likely some step was missed above, my instructions are incorrect, or there is a possible hardware failure. Make sure your headset is turned on.

In the instructions below, the `bluetoothctl` app will differ based on your headset and the what app inserts between the square brackets, where `your-headset-brand` appears as the prompt. It’s best to try these instructions while running the `bluetoothctl` app.

```
$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]power on
[bluetooth]scan on
(Multiple bluetooth devices in your area should appear per line with its MAC address)
[bluetooth]pair <your-headset-address-as: ##:##:##:##:##:##>
[your-headset-brand]connect <##:##:##:##:##:##>
[your-headset-brand]trust <##:##:##:##:##:##>
```

#### Enable the Auto-Connect Feature of Bluetooth

This is the final install phase that will automate the connect to your bluetooth headset. These instructions should enable your RPi4B to recognize when your bluetooth headset turns on and set it as the audio output device.

```
sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

ADD the two lines below somewhere near the top of lists:

```
# Automatically switch to newly-connected devices
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

Save the file above. Uncomment and set `AutoEnable=true` in [Policy] section of the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Save the file above and reboot to enable the auto-connect feature.

```
reboot
```

Turn off your headset and wait for your RPi4B to boot windows desktop then turn the headset back on. It should automatically connect as indicated by beeps in the headset. These instructions were based on the headset model below and no income was generated by this reference. It is only meant to be a reference device that worked for testing the above instructions.
[iJoy Rechargeable Wireless Bluetooth Over-Ear Foldable Headset](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HNMTCE2)

Once your headset connects, you should be able to play audio files through your favorite audio playback app, like `vlc`. If you have problems with audio, try running the `pulseaudio` app located in the main menu under Sounds & Video as PulseAudio Volume Control.

#### References and Sources

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth
- Source code of instructions above as a raw script at the bottom of page:
  https://gist.github.com/frankgould/db38ca5e40b3d2368f8d7765e346f8c5#file-raw-script
- Exton RaspArch Rpi4 Arch Linux ARM 4.19 Build 190809: http://raspex.exton.se/?p=1214

Answer (score 1):

On an 4B running Kodi on Arch Linux with kernel `5.15.24-1-rpi-ARCH`, I had to use the following steps to get bluetooth running and connect to Bose NC 700 headphones:

1. Install `bluez`, `pulseaudio-bluetooth` and associated packages:

   ```
   sudo pacman -S bluez bluez-utils pulseaudio-bluetooth
   ```
2. Enable kernel bluetooth support in `/boot/config.txt`, by uncommenting or adding the following line to it (as suggested in [the README for bluetooth-rpb](https://github.com/WTFThatPerson/bluetooth-rbp)):

   ```
   dtparam=krnbt=on
   ```

   Without this, `rfkill` would not list any bluetooth devices, and if  `bluetooth.service` was started, it wouldn't do anything.
3. Uncomment the following line in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` as suggested in [this Arch Linux ARM forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1696315#p1696315):

   ```
   AutoEnable=true
   ```

   This should be in the `[Policy]` Section. A full example:

   ```
   [Policy]
   # AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
   # This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged
   # in later on. Defaults to 'false'.
   AutoEnable=true
   ```
4. Restart. These steps were enough for the bluetooth device to show up in `rfkill`, and for `bluetoothctl` to start working.
5. Additionally for connecting to the Bose NC 700, I had to switch the controller mode to `bredr` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` as suggested in [this Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293967/70524) as otherwise only the Low Energy mode of the headphones would show and fail to connect:

   ```
   [General]
   # Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
   # is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
   # Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
   ControllerMode = bredr
   ```

   Simply restarting `bluetooth.service` should be enough for this change, but I restarted anyway.

Now I could pair with the headphones using `bluetoothctl`, and Kodi automatically picked up the change in audio device via Pulseaudio.